# Rewrite URL for attachments

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, seo

I recently used Yeost SEO to redirect all my Attachments (images) to the parent post pages (image galleries).

In doing this the Attachment URLS have changed, caused me a whole host of issues!

They were
https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/chateau-vp-hall-with-windows/

Not they have post categories etc included

http://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/residential/chateau-vp/chateau-vp-hall-with-windows/

Can I use htaccess rewrite rule to put them back, to just the filename without categories?

Thanks (I am a bit of a noob...)

J

Comment: You wouldn't use HTAccess rules, this is a WP rewrite rules problem, I'd recommend turning off whatever option you enabled in Yoast

Comment: I recently used a rewrite in HTAcess to change the URL of my news feed posts, removed the "?news" and added "/blog/" then refreshed the permalink options in Wordpress Dashboard.. I was assuming there would be a way to do this similar thing in this case maybe?

Comment: Any idea how to do this within Wordpress as a rewrite? I think I jumped the gun here, sorry :D

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "the attachment URLs have changed?" The actual server URLs don't change when you toggle that Yoast setting. If you go into the media library you'll see they are something like `https://www.obsidianurbexphotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/myfilename.jpg` both with and without that setting enabled. If you want to access them through a pretty permalink you just need to turn that Yoast setting back off.

Comment: @Obsidian Have you contacted Yoast SEO support?

Comment: @WebElaine Yes it is the pretty permalinks that have changed. Previously the image in question was not attached to a post. I attached it to a post...and now it has part of the post added to the URL before the filename. The issue is that on Google the image no returns a 404, I presume as the permalink have changed to include domain.com//category/post/filename whereas before it was just domain.com/filename. Would there be a wordpress rewrite rule to remove the category/post and just have domain.com/filename as before? That would fix the issue perfectly :) (thanks for helping!)

Comment: @TomJNowell dropping them a message as well..

Comment: @Obsidian so it sounds like the change you're concerned about happened because you attached the image to a post - which doesn't have anything to do with your Yoast settings. Also - if you're talking about a Google Image search showing your images, they use the full filename with .jpg, not the pretty permalink - so the issue there is, now that you've attached it to a post, it's changed folder locations to whenever your post was published. Media you upload to a post get stored in the published-date folder, versus media you upload in the library which are stored in an upload-date folder.